# mapstruct for protobuff classess with protobuf-spi-impl

Tags: java, mapstruct, protobuf-java

I am mapping protobtuff generated classes to Lombok annotated DTOs.

my maven config:

```
<properties>
        <mapstruct.version>1.5.1.Final</mapstruct.version>
        <lombok.version>1.18.24</lombok.version>
        <protobuf-spi-impl.version>1.41</protobuf-spi-impl.version>
</properties>
...
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>

                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
                            <version>0.2.0</version>
                        </path>

                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                            <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                        </path>

                        <path>
                            <groupId>no.entur.mapstruct.spi</groupId>
                            <artifactId>protobuf-spi-impl</artifactId>
                            <version>${protobuf-spi-impl.version}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
                        <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                        <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
                    </dependency>

                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
                        <version>0.2.0</version>
                    </dependency>

                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        <version>${lombok.version}</version>
                    </dependency>

                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>no.entur.mapstruct.spi</groupId>
                        <artifactId>protobuf-spi-impl</artifactId>
                        <version>${protobuf-spi-impl.version}</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>

...
```

one of mapper interfaces:

```
@Mapper(
        collectionMappingStrategy = CollectionMappingStrategy.ADDER_PREFERRED,
        componentModel = "spring",
        uses = {ProtobufStandardMappings.class}
)
public interface BaseDataMapper {
    BaseDataDto map(Common.BaseData baseData);

    Common.BaseData map(BaseDataDto dto);
}
```

and finally the error I'm getting:

```
No implementation was created for BaseDataMapper due to having a problem in the erroneous element com.google.type.Date. Hint: this often means that some other annotation processor was supposed to process the erroneous element. You can also enable MapStruct verbose mode by setting -Amapstruct.verbose=true as a compilation argument.
```

so why is that, what should I change?
thanks

Comment: I'd suggest to re-arrange the order of the annotation processors in your pom.xml so that MapStruct runs last, after Lombok and protobuf.

Comment: trying to rearrange that left and right, but doesn't seem to do anything.